# Linux: clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered

Tags: linux, mount

NFS mounts recently automatically got un-mounted. When I checked, the NFS service status it was shown to be running.

```
[root@hsluasrepo]# service nfs status
rpc.svcgssd is stopped
rpc.mountd (pid 4083) is running...
nfsd (pid 4148 4147 4146 4145 4144 4143 4142 4141) is running...
rpc.rquotad (pid 4079) is running...

[root@hsluasrepo]# service rpcbind status
rpcbind (pid  4203) is running...

[root@hsluasrepo common]# rpcinfo -p 10.80.3.154
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
```

But `showmount` output was showing an error.

```
[root@hsluasrepo ]# showmount -e 10.80.3.154
clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered
```

After restarting the NFS service, `showmount` output displayed the NFS server's export list.

Can anyone tell me the root cause of this issue and How to avoid this problem in future?

`/var/log/messages`:

```
Jul 7 03:22:01 hsluasrepo rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="1188" x-info="rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Jul 7 03:22:02 hsluasrepo rhsmd: In order for Subscription Manager to provide your system with updates, your system must be registered with RHN. Please enter your Red Hat login to ensure your system is up-to-date.
Jul 8 03:22:01 hsluasrepo rhsmd: In order for Subscription Manager to provide your system with updates, your system must be registered with RHN. Please enter your Red Hat login to ensure your system is up-to-date.
Jul 8 16:36:55 hsluasrepo kernel: nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache
Jul 8 16:36:55 hsluasrepo rpc.mountd[4083]: Caught signal 15, un-registering and exiting.
Jul 8 16:36:55 hsluasrepo rpc.mountd[24463]: Version 1.2.3 starting
Jul 8 16:36:55 hsluasrepo kernel: NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
Jul 8 16:36:55 hsluasrepo kernel: NFSD: starting 90-second grace period
Jul 8 16:37:32 hsluasrepo rpc.mountd[24463]: authenticated mount request from 10.60.5.208:1004 for /common/PROD (/common/PROD)
Jul 8 16:38:09 hsluasrepo rpc.mountd[24463]: authenticated mount request from 10.60.5.181:869 for /common/PROD (/common/PROD) 
Jul 8 16:38:43 hsluasrepo rpc.mountd[24463]: authenticated mount request from 10.60.5.180:825 for /common/PROD (/common/PROD)
Jul 8 16:39:12 hsluasrepo rpc.mountd[24463]: authenticated mount request from 10.60.5.176:688 for /common/PROD (/common/PROD)
```

Comment: I would check my dmesg log and /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages for signs that the NFS service threw any errors. Also the disks that the NFS share are comprised of, are they in a RAID of any sort? If a member of the RAID failed the share may have gone into an unusable state.

Comment: check if nfs deamon is running on nfs server where the shares are exported

Comment: Since it's really a too nonsensical error message I requested clarification at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=152151. Maybe we'll know one day what is actually meant by it.

Answer (score 12):

you have to:

```
root@10.80.3.154]$ service nfs status
rpc.svcgssd is stopped
rpc.mountd is stopped
nfsd is stopped
rpc.rquotad is stopped

root@10.80.3.154]$ service nfs start
Starting NFS services:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting NFS quotas:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS mountd:                                       [  OK  ]

root@10.80.3.154]$ chkconfig nfs on
```

Comment: `service status nfs`?

Answer (score 5):

I faced this issue on RHEL6. It is strange, but running `service rpcbind restart` before the nfs service made the error go away. I followed this article: [Configure NFS Server step by step in RHEL6](http://computernetworkingnotes.com/network-administration/how-to-configure-nfs-server-in-rhel-6.html)

This worked for me, but I still would like to know the reason behind it. Can anyone explain?

Comment: If you put a question together with you an answer, few people are going to see it. Take the last sentence out and make it into a new question (refer to this Q&A as a solution, but not an explanation).

Comment: @rohit - That indeed solved the problem. RPCBIND service restart before NFS service.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and I resolved it using a simple approach to nfs server and client configuration it involves like 10 steps.

1. install nfs-utils and check to make sure it is installed (`yum install -y nfs-utils / rpm -qa | grep nfs-utils`)
2. `vi /etc/sysconfig/nfs` (uncomment and change the port numbers of the following.. STATD_PORT=, MOUNTD_PORT=, LOCKD_UDPPORT=, LOCKED_TCPPORT={you can use 4000-4004 or any of your choice}
3. `system-config-firewall-tui` {Open the port numbers specified in 2 above and also 111 (rpc) and 2049 (nfs)}
4. `iptables save`
5. `vi /etc/export` (provide the directory to share and where to share it to and the options eg. `/share     *(ro,async)`
6. `exportfs -rv`
7. `service nfs start`
8. `ssh root@clientserver`. eg. `ssh root@192.168.2.15`
9. `showmount -e {master ip}` eg. `showmount -e 192.168.2.31`
10. `mount -t nfs {master ip}:/{shared dir from master}  /{mount point}` .. eg. `mount -t nfs 192.168.2.31:/share /mnt`

Finally, do a `df -h`.

This is just my little contribution; I may not have taken all the necessary steps, but this may help.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that your NFS is running on version 4 only

try mounting on client using following if it successfully executes then assume that NFS is only allowing NFSv4:

```
#mkdir /mount_point

#mount -t nfs4 nfs_servername:/ /mount_point
```

If you want to enable other nfs version make following changes in  /etc/sysconfig/nfs:

**comment following**

```
RPCNFSDARGS="-N 2 -N 3 -U"
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="-N 2 -N 3"
```

And configure following:

```
# vim /etc/nfs.conf

[nfsd]
vers3=y
vers4=y
vers4.0=y
vers4.1=y
vers4.2=y
```

---

```
#systemctl restart nfs
#exportfs -r -v
```

Answer (score 1):

i've recently configured NFS in RHEL on a virtual machine and the same problem appear when i set showmount -e localhost command. After trying to restart services several times, i`ve just poweroff my virtual machine and poweron again and the problem was solved.

Regards!!